# Using VBA to fill an Access Database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to connect an Excel Spreadsheet to Access in order to publish the information from the spreadsheet to the access DB. I'm collecting all the information from the spreadsheet and putting it into a vector and then using the ActiveX Data Objects library to insert the information.

Here is the code:

```
Sub AddRecordToAccess()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    Dim dbPath As String
    dbPath = "C:\Users\julorteg1\Documents\ParrillaTelevision.accdb"
    
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";"
    conn.Open
    
    Dim sql As String
    
    'Obtener los datos
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(2, 1)) Then
        'Si no hay nada en la BD entonces no toca revisar duplicados
        Dim BD_range As Range
        Dim BD_array() As Variant
        
         If IsEmpty(Cells(3, 1)) Then
            Set BD_range = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight))
            BD_array = vectorizar_datos_matrix(BD_range)
        Else
            Set BD_range = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
            BD_array = vectorizar_datos_matrix(BD_range)
        End If
        
        ' Hacer la consulta
        i = 1
        V1 = BD_array(i, 1)
        V2 = BD_array(i, 2)
        V3 = BD_array(i, 3)
        V4 = BD_array(i, 4)
        V5 = BD_array(i, 5)
        V6 = BD_array(i, 6)
        V7 = BD_array(i, 7)
        V8 = BD_array(i, 8)
        V9 = BD_array(i, 9)
        V10 = BD_array(i, 10)
        V11 = BD_array(i, 11)
        V12 = BD_array(i, 12)
        V13 = BD_array(i, 13)
        
        sql = "INSERT INTO Parilla (MarcaID,CategoriaID,CanalID,Mes,Year_A,Dia,ProgramaID,Duracion,Salidas,CampañaID,TipoPagoID,TipoFacturacionID,TRPs) VALUES (V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,V7,V8,V9,V10,V11,V12,V13)"
        conn.Execute sql
    
        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
    
    Else
        MsgBox "No hay datos"
    End If 
End Sub 

' ---- Funciones auxiliares ----
'Funcion que transforma los rangos en matrices
Function vectorizar_datos_matrix(datos As Range)
    '-Variables para asignar los tamaños a las matrices de datos
    Dim rowsDatos As Double
    Dim columnsDatos As Double
    'Asignar
    rowsDatos = datos.Rows.Count
    columnsDatos = datos.Columns.Count
    
    '-Variables auxiliares
    'Declarar
    Dim rowsCounter As Double
    Dim columnsCounter As Double
    Dim datos_v() As Variant
    'Asignar
    rowsCounter = 1
    columnsCounter = 1
    ReDim datos_v(1 To rowsDatos, 1 To columnsDatos) 'Dimensiones del mismo rango
    
    '-Recorrido por los datos
    For Each dato In datos
     'Asignar datos
     datos_v(rowsCounter, columnsCounter) = dato
     'Arreglar las filas y columnas
     columnsCounter = columnsCounter + 1
     If columnsCounter > columnsDatos Then
        columnsCounter = 1
        rowsCounter = rowsCounter + 1
     End If
    Next dato
    
    'Retornar la matriz
    vectorizar_datos_matrix = datos_v

End Function
```

The data is right here:
[image]

And the database was planned like this:

[image]

There is a constant error that keeps poping up and I can't figure (and that's driving me crazy) what is "Run-time error '-2147217904 (80040e10)' No value given for one or more required parameters" I double checked and there isn't anything missing in the SQL query, the information is in a vector because the idea is to make a for loop to loop over when there are multiple records in the spread sheet.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: `...VALUES (V1,V2,V3....` this does not substitute the value in `V1` etc into the SQL: it passes "V1", etc. Should be  `...VALUES (" & V1 & "," & V2 & "," & V3 &....`

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL needs to contain the variable *values*, not the literal "V1", "V2" etc.

You could use something like this:

```vb
Const SQL = "INSERT INTO Parilla (MarcaID,CategoriaID,CanalID,Mes,Year_A, " & _
            "Dia,ProgramaID,Duracion,Salidas,CampañaID,TipoPagoID,TipoFacturacionID,TRPs)" & _
            "VALUES (<V1>,<V2>,<V3>,<V4>,<V5>,<V6>,<V7>,<V8>,<V9>,<V10>,<V11>,<V12>,<V13>)"

Dim s As String, i As Long, n As Long, v

i = 1
s = SQL
For n = 1 To 13
    v = BD_array(i, n)
    s = Replace(s, "<" & n & ">", IIf(Len(v) > 0, v, "null")) 'handle empty values
Next n
conn.Execute s
```

Comment: ... or invest the time and use `ADODB.Parameter`. Just to prevent the next two questions: "Why do I get an error when I want to insert a text" and "Why do I get an error when I want to insert a date".